# Retrieving entity records before savingchanges

Tags: wpf, linq, entity-framework

I just have not been able to find an answer to this anywhere and I'm hoping someone can help me.  I'm a newbie on WPF and Entity Framework, so probably doing this all wrong.

I've got a situation where I'm creating new records and adding them to an Entity collection.  I do not want to perform a SaveChanges() on it yet to allow the user to finish everything they want to do and then do a final Save before leaving the form.  My problem is that after the records have been added to the Entity collection, I can not retrieve them back out for display 'until' they have had the SaveChanges() ran on the entity.

This is basically a Master-Child display using two DataGrids but the Master grid source is a List<> being built since one of the fields in the table needs to be converted to a more user friendly display.  And this is all coming from one table where I'm just grouping the data based on 3 of the fields (as the Master) and then displaying the child grid as the details of that grouping.

This action is a 'Copy' action where I'm taking an existing DataGrid display of data and letting the user copy the data to a 'new' master group.  I'm using the following to create this new group of records.

```
            RateGroupRow rgr = new RateGroupRow();
            rgr.StaffRole = rg.SelectedStaffRole;
            rgr.Department = rg.SelectedDepartment;
            rgr.PlanYear = rg.SelectedPlanYear;
            _rateGroupQuery.Add(rgr);

            foreach (var item in dgRateValues.Items)
            {
                if (item.GetType() == typeof(CommissionRate))
                {
                    CommissionRate cr = (CommissionRate)item;
                    CommissionRate newcr = new CommissionRate();
                    newcr.StaffRole = Common.StaffTextToStaffType(rgr.StaffRole);
                    newcr.Department = rgr.Department;
                    newcr.PlanYear = rgr.PlanYear;
                    newcr.Low = cr.Low;
                    newcr.High = cr.High;
                    newcr.Rate = cr.Rate;
                    Common.CommissionsEntities.CommissionRates.AddObject(newcr);
                }
            }
            //TODO:  Don't want to do this SaveChanges here but for now that's the only way I can get these new records to be displayed in the data selection.
            //Common.CommissionsEntities.SaveChanges();

            dgRateGroups.ItemsSource = null;
            dgRateGroups.ItemsSource = _rateGroupQuery;
            dgRateGroups.SelectedIndex = dgRateGroups.Items.Count - 2;
```

After the Master record has been added to the _rateGroupQuery, the DataGrid (dgRateGroups) selects that row in which the SelectionChanged queries for the data to populate the details DataGrid as:

```
    dgRateValues.ItemsSource = null;
    _CurrentSelectedStaffRole = rateGroupRow.StaffRole;
    _CurrentSelectedDepartment = rateGroupRow.Department;
    _CurrentSelectedPlanYear = rateGroupRow.PlanYear;
    string StaffNameType = Common.StaffTextToStaffType(_CurrentSelectedStaffRole);

    var CommissionRatesItems =
        from cr in Common.CommissionsEntities.CommissionRates
        where cr.StaffRole == StaffNameType &&
              cr.Department == _CurrentSelectedDepartment &&
              cr.PlanYear == _CurrentSelectedPlanYear
        orderby cr.Low
        select cr;
    ObjectQuery<CommissionRate> CommissionRatesQuery = CommissionRatesItems as ObjectQuery<CommissionRate>;
    dgRateValues.ItemsSource = CommissionRatesQuery.Execute(MergeOption.AppendOnly);
```

I get no records back from this select.  If I do the 'SaveChanges()' call after adding the records, then everything works fine.

So is there a way to retrieve these newly added records prior to them being committed (SaveChanges) back to the database?

Thank you,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

You can get them back, but not in the ObjectQuery. You instead would have to go through the ObjectStateManager and find Added entities and then build your binding list from that. This is a pain and doesn't work very well.

Fortunately, if you use DbContext as shipped with EF 4.1 and above then the data binding experience is much nicer. DbContext provides you with an ObservableCollection for each type of entity as the .Local property on the entity's DbSet. This collection has all the events hooked up for data binding and automatically includes newly Added entities while also excluding entities marked for deletion. More information and a walkthrough can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574514.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much Arthur, I'll check out the link.  I believe I'm just using EF 4.0 since I'm building on Framework 4.0, but I'll look into this.